# setting attribute value of an element as a numeric value stored in a variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(".slick-next").click(function(){
    var i = parseInt(i)+1;
    jQuery("[data-slick-index=i]").addClass("slick-current");
});
```

I want to add a class slick-current to the element which has attribute value i which is a numeric value.I tried the above code,but failed.Anyone pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 jQuery(".slick-next").click(function(){
    var i = parseInt(i)+1;
    jQuery("[data-slick-index=" + i + "]").addClass("slick-current");
 });
```

Note that I'm unsure about your variable declaration for `i`: That `i` is declared as `parseInt(i)` suggests that `i` is already declared before to have any value at all, and in this case you would declare the same variable twice.

Comment: @jaina Glad that I was able to help :)